# Обратная польская запись с дробными числами

Tags: java, android, алгоритм, польская-запись

Пишу калькулятор на Android,и решил использовать ОПЗ т.к там можно использовать скобки, и столкнулся с проблемой что не могу в ней использовать дробные числа, как это исправить?

```
public class RPN {
static boolean isDelim(char c) { // тру если пробел
    return c == ' ';
}
static boolean isOperator(char c) { // возвращаем тру если один из символов ниже
    return c == '+' || c == '-' || c == '*' || c == '/' || c == '%';
}
static int priority(char op) {
    switch (op) { // при + или - возврат 1, при * / % 2 иначе -1
        case '+':
        case '-':
            return 1;
        case '*':
        case '/':
        case '%':
            return 2;
        default:
            return -1;
    }
}
static void processOperator(LinkedList<Integer> st, char op) {
    int r = st.removeLast(); // выдёргиваем из упорядоченного листа 
последний элемент
    int l = st.removeLast(); // также
    switch (op) { // выполняем действие между l и r в зависимости от 
оператора в кейсе и результат валим в st
        case '+':
            st.add(l + r);
            break;
        case '-':
            st.add(l - r);
            break;
        case '*':
            st.add(l * r);
            break;
        case '/':
            st.add(l / r);
            break;
        case '%':
            st.add(l % r);
            break;
    }
}
public static String eval(String s) {
    LinkedList<Integer> st = new LinkedList<Integer>(); // сюда наваливают 
цифры
    LinkedList<Character> op = new LinkedList<Character>(); // сюда 
операторы и st и op в порядке поступления
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) { // парсим строку с выражением и 
вычисляем
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if (isDelim(c))
            continue;
        if (c == '(')
            op.add('(');
        else if (c == ')') {
            while (op.getLast() != '(')
                processOperator(st,op.removeLast());
            op.removeLast();
        } else if (isOperator(c)) {
            while (!op.isEmpty() && priority(op.getLast()) >= priority(c))
                processOperator(st, op.removeLast());
            op.add(c);
        } else {
            String operand = "";
            while (i < s.length() && Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i)))
                operand += s.charAt(i++);
            --i;
            st.add(Integer.parseInt(operand));
        }
    }
    while (!op.isEmpty())
        processOperator(st, op.removeLast());
    return st.get(0).toString();  // возврат результата
    }
}
```

Comment: Как минимум исправьте коллекцию на LinkedList<Double> и добавьте в ваш парсер возможность обработки дробных чисел (например с помощью регулярки). А ещё лучше использовать для этих целей класс BigDecimal.

Comment: Тк в том и проблема что я не знаю как,добавить возможность обработки дробных чисел.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    String operand = "";
    boolean isContainDot = false;
    while (i < s.length() && (Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i)) || s.charAt(i)=='.')) {
        if (s.charAt(i)=='.') {
            if (isContainDot) throw new ParseException(s+" at position "+i,i);
            else isContainDot = true;
        }
        operand += s.charAt(i++);
    }
    --i;
    st.add(Double.parseDouble(operand));
```

навскидку как-то так. И тип коллекции поменяйте.